# Proving set equality

Tags: elementary-set-theory, discrete-mathematics, logic

Prove that the two sets A and B below are equal.

$A = \{ 7m − 5 : m \in \mathbb{Z} \}$
$B = \{14k + b : k \in \mathbb{Z}, b \in \{2,9\} \}$

Following an example I was given, my first step was to do a little algebra to find that if $7m-5 = 14k+2$, then $m=2k+1$ and if $7m-5 = 14k+9$ then $m=2k+2$.

This example then led me to prove $ A \subseteq B$ as follows: Suppose $x \in A$, then $x=7m-5, m \in \mathbb{Z}$. Let $m = 2k+1$, so $7m-5 = 7(2k+1)-5 = 14k+7-5 = 14k+2 = x\in B$, by the definition of B. As such, $x \in B$, which implies that $ A \subseteq B$

**First question:** Am I really allowed to choose the $m$ value here - doesn't this need to be true for an arbitrary $m$? My thinking is that this is okay because I'm "choosing" $m$ as a function of an arbitrary $k$, but don't have my head wrapped around this well enough yet to be confident about that.

**Second question:** Do I also need to show that, if $m=2k+2$, then $x=14k+9 \in B$? I'm thinking I don't, because if the answer to my first question is "yes" then I would already have shown that $x \in B$ for one b value, so the second case is unnecessary. But my confusion surrounding the first question is clouding my reasoning about this.

**Third question:** How might I apply this approach to prove that $B \subseteq A$? $\mathbb{Z}$ is not closed under division so I can't say "let $k = m/2 -1$", can I?

**Fourth question:** Am I just barking up the wrong tree here, and taking the wrong basic approach? I have a suspicion that I am - if so, kindly point me in a better direction

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not free to choose to let $m = 2k+1$ since not all $m$ used in defining $A$ are odd. And that is the flaw that made you thik that the $9$ value was superfluous.

You *are* free to consider two cases, one if $m = 2k+1$ and one if $m=2k$, because for any integer $m$, one of those cases is surely true.  And you will find when you do that that $b=9$ is necessary for the second case.

As to your third question, no you can't let $k = m/2 - 1$.  But you can let $b = 2$, then divide by $2$ and use $m=k+1$.  That covers half of $B$; you can also let $b=9$ and then take $m = 2(k+1)$.

Your approach is OK, but this problem does break up into two cases (in each direction) and you can't easily avoid the other half of the work.

Comment: Beautiful, thanks! I was really hoping I was wrong about that - the whole concept makes much more sense to me with this being the case